# Gridview element’s background depending on whether the binded object is an element of the list in application for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, multibinding

Welcome.

It’s the first time, that I can’t find solution on this website and I have to ask own question. I have list (List1) of objects my class Cell. This objects are binded to a Gridview. GridviewElements has Grid, which background I want to change each time the binded object is being added to or removed from other list (List2).

Firstly, I was trying to achieve it by using WinRTMultiBinding 
(https://github.com/Verbon/WinRTMultiBinding), but it seems that can only bind simple types, not Cell and list of it. Then I started to trying initialize IValueConverter object in VievModel, but couldn’t bind it to {Binding Converter}. After that I decided to declare and pass List2 to the converter as a field, but it didn’t changed through the time. My last try, was declaring static field in ViewModel class that contains current reference, but as the GridViewElement binds only Cell object which is not changing, the PropertyChanged event is not raised, so the colour stays the same.

I’m now thinking about declaring a new property in Cell class that represents brush, or new list of cell brushes to be bind as background, but I hope there is better solution. And there is my question: do You know any?

My XAML code:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="2" Width="30" Height="30" CornerRadius="2"  Tag="{Binding}" 
                        BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CellToBrush}}"
                        PointerPressed="OnCrosswordGridViewItemPointerPressed">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Name="Character" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundMain}" Text="{Binding Char}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

There is my VM:
It contains

- Crossword object - model for that page which contains list of Cells
  List1 (named `Cells`)
- VM's deffinition of it (named the same as in model)
- Deffinition of `StartCell` that represents first Cell that user
  presses down
- Deffinition of `ObservableCollection` of `Cell` `SelectedCells` - this is the List2

  ```
  Crossword crossword;   

  public List<Cell> Cells
  {
      get { return crossword.Cells; }

  }

  Cell startCell;
  public Cell StartCell
  {
      set
      {
          if(value != startCell)
          {
              startCell = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("StartCell");
          }
      }
      get { return startCell; }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Cell> SelectedCells 
  {
      get;set;
  }
  ```

And methods in code behind:

```
 void OnCellPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            CreateCrosswordPageVM vm = (CreateCrosswordPageVM)DataContext;
            vm.StartCell = (Cell)((Border)sender).Tag;
        }
    }

    void OnCrosswordGridViewItemPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        CreateCrosswordPageVM vm = (CreateCrosswordPageVM)DataContext;
        Cell currentCell = (Cell)((Border)sender).Tag;
        if (currentCell.Row == vm.StartCell.Row && currentCell.Column > vm.StartCell.Column)
            vm.SelectedCells = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Cell>(vm.Cells.FindAll(x=>x.Row == currentCell.Row && x.Column<= currentCell.Column && x.Column>= vm.StartCell.Column));
        else if (currentCell.Column == vm.StartCell.Column && currentCell.Row > vm.StartCell.Row)
            vm.SelectedCells = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Cell>(vm.Cells.FindAll(x=>x.Column== currentCell.Column && x.Row <= currentCell.Row && x.Row >= vm.StartCell.Row));
    }
```

First method passes the "pressed" `Cell` to ViewModel's `StartCell`, second checks which Cells lies between `StartCell` and current `Cell` (over which the pointer is) and passes them to `SelectedCells`.

And about the colours. I wanted to hardcode it in `Converter` and later when it works, pass them as `Converter` parameter or daclare is as resources in `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: What  "GridviewElements"  you mean here? `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Yes. I set my own DataTemplate to GridView ItemTeplate.

Comment: What is the `List2`, could you please for example?  Did the List2 is also the cells same as List1? Or a color list? Did the List2 bind to any control?  For "is being added to or removed " , how you do it currently?

Comment: I added more code with explenation. I hope it is what you asked for.